# How to open file that is stored by CarrierWave in GridFs from a rails model? (File.open issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWave to store files in gridfs, but having problems with opening them from my model. 
Here are my configs:

/config/initialize/carrierwave.rb

```
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.grid_fs_database = Mongoid.database.name
  config.grid_fs_host = Mongoid.config.master.connection.host
  config.storage = :grid_fs
  config.grid_fs_access_url = "/files"
end
```

/app/controllers/gridfs_controller.rb

```
 /require 'mongo' 
        class GridfsController < ActionController::Metal
          def serve
            gridfs_path = env["PATH_INFO"].gsub("/files/", "")
            begin
              gridfs_file = Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(Mongoid.database).open(gridfs_path, 'r')
              self.response_body = gridfs_file.read
              self.content_type = gridfs_file.content_type
            rescue
              self.status = :file_not_found
              self.content_type = 'text/plain'
              self.response_body = ''
            end
          end
        end
```

/app/uploaders/list_uploader.rb

```
class ListUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :grid_fs
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

and in routes

```
match "/files/uploads/*path" => "gridfs#serve"
```

So, I have a model, which have a text file

```
class Campaign
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :list, ListUploader
```

When I'm calling something like `<%=link_to "List", @campaign.list.url %>` from my view, it opens fine. But when I'm trying something like `File.open("#{campaign.list.url}", "r")` from campaign model, it fails. It gives me `false` even when I'm calling `File.exists?("/files/uploads/campaign/list/4eb02c4d6b1c0f02b200000b/list.txt")`, which is a proper url for that file. So, the question is how should I call it, to open the file from model? And for some reasons, it is important to open it from model. Any suggestions would help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrierwave url with mongodb gridfs is not a physical path. Its merely a logical route to download the file from gridfs. Thats why you cannot access it from ruby `File.open`. Check out the below snippet from rails console trying to open the file from gridfs

```
File.open(User.first.image.pic.url,'r')
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /images/uploads/e5a1007d34.jpg
```

see it throw No such file or directory., So you have to download a file instead opening by

```
>> require 'open-uri'
>> open('image.jpg', 'wb') do |file|
?> file << open('http://0.0.0.0:3000' + (User.first.image.pic.url)).read
>> p file
>> end
#<File:image.jpg>
=> #<File:image.png (closed)>
```

Comment: yup, that worked up just great, thank you! As well as this [option](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.GridFS.html#the-gridfilesystem-class)